# Extract elements from a list given the positions in another list

Tags: r

I have a list of matrices as follow.

```
listMat <- list(A=matrix(1:9, ncol=3), B=matrix(10:18, ncol=3))
listMat 

$A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

$B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   13   16
[2,]   11   14   17
[3,]   12   15   18
```

I want to extract  1st and 2nd column of the matrix A and the 3rd column of B.
These positions are given in the list.

```
listPosition <- list(A=c(1,2), B=c(1))
listPosition 
$A
[1] 1 2

$B
[1] 1
```

Is there a way to extract elements rather than the using the following command

```
  listMat[["A"]][,1:2] 
  listMat[["B"]][,1]
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `Map` to extract the corresponding `matrix` elements in the `list` using the index in `listPosition`

```
Map(function(x, y) x[, y, drop = FALSE], listMat, listPosition)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sapply(names(listMat), function(x) listMat[[x]][,listPosition[[x]], drop = FALSE])
#$A
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    4
#[2,]    2    5
#[3,]    3    6

#$B
#     [,1]
#[1,]   10
#[2,]   11
#[3,]   12
```

Comment: This answer is more correct than the first one. For example, if listPosition <- list(A=c(1,2),), then the 2nd answer gives the correct results.